# Using Minimum-Redundancy Maximum-Relevancy (mrmr) Method with large Matrix return errors. Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, redundancy, relevance

I am working with a feature selection method called `mrmr`. I found the mrmr code [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14608-mrmr-feature-selection--using-mutual-information-computation-)
When I am running `mrmr_mid_d(d,f,K)` with `d=62x2000`, `f=62x1` and `K=25` I got the following error:

> Error using estpab  Requested 12962x19852 (1.9GB) array exceeds
>   maximum array size preference. Creation of  arrays greater than this
>   limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become  unresponsive.
>   See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

It works fine having `d=62x100`, `f=62x1` and `K=10`, but does not in the case of a 2000 attribute.

Comment: Matlab version? OS version?

Comment: my matlab version 2015a and os windows 10 .